# RAM modules with different frequency issue

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I have a PC with the following specs

CPU: [Intel Core i5-7500 Kaby Lake](http://findhard.ru/en/processors/model?id=1142&m=intel-core-i5-7500-kaby-lake-3400mhz-lga1151-l3-6144kb)

motherboard: [GIGABYTE GA-H110M-S2PV](http://findhard.ru/en/motherboards/model?id=3628&m=gigabyte-ga-h110m-s2pv-rev-10)

RAM: 1x [AMD R748G2133U2S-UO](http://findhard.ru/en/rams/model?id=9195&m=amd-r748g2133u2s-uo)

Recently I bought another RAM module [AMD R748G2400U2S-UO](http://findhard.ru/en/rams/model?id=9834&m=amd-r748g2400u2s-uo) and installed it. At first, everything was fine, PC booted and recognized all 16 GB of RAM. But after a few hours of work, a screen image froze and all sounds stopped playing. It didn't pass by itself so I had to hard reset the PC. It happened multiple times with the same scenario.

I figured out that this issue was somehow related to RAM modules. I've tried all possible combinations of my modules like

- only old module in slot 1 or slot 2
- only new module in slot 1 or slot 2
- both modules with different positioning

Both new and old modules worked fine and stable until only one module was installed. While any combination of both modules resulted in a freeze described above.

I've tried to play with BIOS settings but I'm not very good at it. That's what I tried:

- Set option **Memory Enhancement Settings** in BIOS to **Enhanced stability**.
- Set option **Memory timing settings** to **manual** and set the timings to 16-16-16-36 as for the new module with frequency 2400 as they are higher than old's ones.

None of these helped. Is there a way I can make these two modules work fine?

Thanks in advance for the answers =)

Comment: [Updated] I just took a look at the motherboard. I never considered a motherboard with only 2 RAM slots (rather than 4). It support dual channel, which means both DIMMs should have the same settings. And that is the lowest common domimator. So do not set the newer RAM to higher speed.   Think of it as two car driving side by side. One night be able to go faster, but to stay next to the other it should go at the same speed, same turn radius etc. And use the lesser common value.

Comment: @Hennes
I was guided by the same principle =)


Old module with frequency 2133 has timings 15-15-15-35.

The new one with frequency 2400 has timings 16-16-16-36.

I thought that here the bigger timing number means less speed so I set it to 16-16-16-36. Should I have set it to 15-15-15-35 instead?

Comment: No. Timing speed 2133 (1066MHz), 16-16-16-36, same voltage. That should just work.

Not sure what else it can be. I am guessing both a regular rank 2 modules, or are you mixing rank 1 and rank 2?

And what happens if you disable dual channel mode and test? Speedup from that usually is small enough that disabling it for stability can be worth it.

Comment: @Hennes I've tried to set up timings like this, my settings are on screenshots by links
https://ibb.co/9ZWq8Pf
https://ibb.co/QCFHBZP
https://ibb.co/p21Dk2G

AAAAAND It's still the same :( Worked fine for 3 hours just to freeze again... How do you think maybe I should change some additional settings to make it work?